# How to listen even choose item from combobox in ZK 7?

Tags: java, zk

I am use MVC design pattern. In file `FmCompress.zul`, I have:

```
<combobox id="cboFmCompress" model="${$composer.listTypeOfProcess}" mold="rounded" hflex="1">
    <attribute name="onCreate">self.setSelectedIndex(1);</attribute>
    <template name="model">
        <comboitem label="${each.typeOfCompress}" value="${each.typeOfCompressId}"></comboitem>
    </template>
</combobox>
```

Model for combo box: `TypeOfCompressDTO.java`

```
public class TypeOfCompressDTO {

    private String typeOfCompressId;
    private String typeOfCompress;

    public TypeOfCompressDTO() {
    }

    public TypeOfCompressDTO(String typeOfCompressId, String typeOfCompress) {
        this.typeOfCompressId = typeOfCompressId;
        this.typeOfCompress = typeOfCompress;
    }

    public String getTypeOfCompressId() {
        return typeOfCompressId;
    }

    public void setTypeOfCompressId(String typeOfCompressId) {
        this.typeOfCompressId = typeOfCompressId;
    }

    public String getTypeOfCompress() {
        return typeOfCompress;
    }

    public void setTypeOfCompress(String typeOfCompress) {
        this.typeOfCompress = typeOfCompress;
    }

}
```

In file controller: `FmCompressComposer.java` , I try something like this (my idea):

```
public class FmCompressComposer extends BaseCustomComposer<FmCompressService, FmCompressDTO> {
     //....    

    @Wire
    private Combobox cboToggleZipUnzip;

    //....

    // initialize value for combo box.
    public ListModel<TypeOfCompressDTO> getListTypeOfProcess() {
        lstTypeOfCompress = new ArrayList<TypeOfCompressDTO>();
        TypeOfCompressDTO t1 = new TypeOfCompressDTO("1", "Zip file");
        TypeOfCompressDTO t2 = new TypeOfCompressDTO("2", "Unzip file");
        lstTypeOfCompress.add(t1);
        lstTypeOfCompress.add(t2);
        listTypeOfProcess = new ListModelList(lstTypeOfCompress, true);
        return listTypeOfProcess;
    }

     // Listen even select item in combo box.
     public void onSelect$cboZipUnzip(){   
        searchDTO = new FmCompressDTO();    
        searchDTO.setType("1");        
        // my problem focus at this method, and at this line, get value what user choosen. searchDTO.setType(cboToggleZipUnzip.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString());
        List<FmCompressDTO> listDTO = fmCompressService.search(searchDTO);
        if (listDTO != null && !listDTO.isEmpty()) {
            ListModelList model = new ListModelList(listDTO);
            model.setMultiple(true);
            gridDataFmCompress.setModel(model);
            refreshGridData(null);
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

Please help me: **In combo box, when user has event selecting, call method.** (In method, get value what user choosen from combobox).

Comment: I can't tell what your problem is. Is it, that the event listener is not called?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, my method event listener not working (I maybe wrong when named method `onSelect$cboZipUnzip()`). And I can't get value what user choosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `BaseCustomComposer` is extending a [`GenericForwardComposer`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/8.0.0-RC/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/util/GenericForwardComposer.html).

If so, you are strictly bound to the naming conventions.

As your id of the combobox is `cboFmCompress` your wired variable should be

```
// no need for @Wire
private Combobox cboFmCompress;
```

and the event listener method should be
    `public void onSelect$cboFmCompress(Event event) {}`

Here you can find a minimized zkfiddle: http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3hnhc92/2-SO-33120026

Comment: It works! help me get value from combobox what user choosen. revise my above snippet in the question, I tried `searchDTO.setType(cboToggleZipUnzip.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString());` but it is't work.

Comment: This would be `searchDTO.setType(cboFmCompress.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString()); ` then. What does debugging `cboFmCompress.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString()` say?

Comment: I have a mistake. After I change a little, it works.